# Unable to setup docker private registry with persistent storage on kubernetes with helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I am trying to set up a docker private registry on kubernetes cluster with helm. But I am getting an error for pvc. The error is:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                  From                   Message
  ----     ------       ----                 ----                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled    22m                  default-scheduler      Successfully assigned docker-reg/docker-private-registry-docker-registry-6454b85dbb-zpdjc to 192.168.1.19
  Warning  FailedMount  2m10s (x9 over 20m)  kubelet, 192.168.1.19  Unable to mount volumes for pod "docker-private-registry-docker-registry-6454b85dbb-zpdjc_docker-reg(82c8be80-eb43-11e8-85c9-b06ebfd124ff)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "docker-reg"/"docker-private-registry-docker-registry-6454b85dbb-zpdjc". list of unmounted volumes=[data]. list of unattached volumes=[auth data docker-private-registry-docker-registry-config default-token-xc4p7]
```

What might be the reason for this error? I've also tried to create a pvc first and then use the existing pvc with docker registry's helm but it gives the same error.

Steps:

1. Create a htpasswd file
2. Edit `values.yml` and add contents of htpasswd file to `htpasswd` key.
3. Modify `values.yml` to enable persistence
4. Run `helm install stable/docker-registry --namespace docker-reg --name docker-private-registry --values helm-docker-reg/values.yml`

`values.yml` file:

```
# Default values for docker-registry.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.
replicaCount: 1

updateStrategy:
  # type: RollingUpdate
  # rollingUpdate:
  #   maxSurge: 1
  #   maxUnavailable: 0

podAnnotations: {}

image:
  repository: registry
  tag: 2.6.2
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
# imagePullSecrets:
    # - name: docker
service:
  name: registry
  type: ClusterIP
  # clusterIP:
  port: 5000
  # nodePort:
  annotations: {}
  # foo.io/bar: "true"
ingress:
  enabled: false
  path: /
  # Used to create an Ingress record.
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  tls:
    # Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
    # - secretName: chart-example-tls
    #   hosts:
    #     - chart-example.local
resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi
persistence:
  accessMode: 'ReadWriteOnce'
  enabled: true
  size: 10Gi
  storageClass: 'rook-ceph-block'

# set the type of filesystem to use: filesystem, s3
storage: filesystem

# Set this to name of secret for tls certs
# tlsSecretName: registry.docker.example.com
secrets:
  haSharedSecret: ""
  htpasswd: "dasdma:$2y$05$bnLaYEdTLawodHz2ULzx2Ob.OUI6wY6bXr9WUuasdwuGZ7TIsTK2W"
# Secrets for Azure
#   azure:
#     accountName: ""
#     accountKey: ""
#     container: ""
# Secrets for S3 access and secret keys
#   s3:
#     accessKey: ""
#     secretKey: ""
# Secrets for Swift username and password
#   swift:
#     username: ""
#     password: ""

# Options for s3 storage type:
# s3:
#  region: us-east-1
#  bucket: my-bucket
#  encrypt: false
#  secure: true

# Options for swift storage type:
# swift:
#  authurl: http://swift.example.com/
#  container: my-container

configData:
  version: 0.1
  log:
    fields:
      service: registry
  storage:
    cache:
      blobdescriptor: inmemory
  http:
    addr: :5000
    headers:
      X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
  health:
    storagedriver:
      enabled: true
      interval: 10s
      threshold: 3

securityContext:
  enabled: true
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000

priorityClassName: ""

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []
```

Comment: Can you share steps that you're performing to do this !

Comment: @murarisumit Added steps

Comment: share how you enabled in values.yml

Comment: @VKR Added values.yml

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. The issue was with the openebs storage which was documented here -  https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/tsgiscsi.html